# "watch" and "df"

Tags: watch-command

When I run `df -h | grep sdc` all is fine, I see numbers in human-readable format:

```
/dev/sdc1       954G  889G   65G  94% /media/bohdan/teamdata
```

When I run `sh -c "df -h | grep sdc"` all is fine, the result is the same...

When I run `watch sh -c "df -h | grep sdc"` ...suddenly I'm no longer eligible to seeing human-readable numbers:

```
/dev/sdc1      1000203520  934440320  65763200  94% /media/bohdan/teamdata
```

Why?

Comment: I find my self using findmnt more and more, `findmnt -Dn /dev/sdc1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because by default, `watch` itself wraps your command in a `sh -c` command. This means that you lose a level of quoting, and your command becomes

```
sh -c df -h | grep sdc
```

so that `sh -c` executes plain `df`, with `-h` being passed as a positional parameter to the shell.

You can either add additional quoting:

```
watch "sh -c 'df -h | grep sdc'"
```

or tell watch not to wrap the command using `-x`:

> ```
>    -x, --exec
>           command is given to sh -c which means that you may need  to  use
>           extra  quoting  to get the desired effect.  This with the --exec
>           option, which passes the command to exec(2) instead.
> ```

or simply run

```
watch "df -h | grep sdc"
```

without the (unnecessary) explicit `sh -c`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to quote the command

```
watch 'sh -c "df -h | grep sdc"'
```

`watch` runs the command given by calling `sh -c`. So what you're doing in effect is running something like `sh -c sh -c "df -h | grep sdc"`.

So I'd say, that `sh -c` in your `watch` parameter is superfluous.